# how to change actions on key pressed in contenteditable tags

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard-events

when I press 'enter' in contenteditable area a new `<div>` is produced what I rather want to add `<br />` tag. How can I manipulate this behaviour. How is it done in WYMeditor. Is there any other method than `preventdefault()` and handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

No. That's the way it's done. In IE, you need to set the event's `returnValue` property to `false` rather than call `preventDefault()` (note the capital D in the middle).